# PHP session.cookie_domain without www

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have the following problem. I redirecting all domain addresses from `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com` via .htaccess file.

Website may also have subdomains: `http://login1.example.com`, `http://other_login.example.com` etc.

Is it possilbe to carry session between subdomains? When url contains `www` everything works fine (`session.cookie_domain = '.example.com'`) How can i solve this without `www` ? (using CodeIgniter)

Answer (score 0):

To change these settings open up the application/config/config.php file. You will find somewhere around line 268 all the settings you require to do what your looking to do.

In the above example change:

```
$config['cookie_domain'] = "";
// to
$config['cookie_domain'] = ".example.com";
```

It would certainly be possible to carry the session between sub-domains if they are using the same Application. I couldn't see why it would be an issue if you are using separate applications either, so long as your encryption keys are the same in both applications.

Comment: Yeap, it works pretty fine when url contains `www`. But it fails when I drop the `www` part from url. Application is fine, i redirect all the subdomains to one controller, for example: `user1.example.com` = `example.com/user_panel/user1`.

Comment: In your web browser can you see if the cookies are being set as expected? I often find it worth flushing the browsers cookies as sometimes you get a stray cookie laying around.